# How to say "Indicates something that is not easy for one to do."

Tags: translation

I'm trying to write my grammar explanation notes in Japanese. I'm trying to write an explanation like "Indicates something that is not easy for one to do." I've come up with

> 自分にされやすくないことを示す。

but I'm not sure if 自分に and passive voice is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

> やりにくい事を示す。

Indicate something is hard to do. (Positive)

> 簡単に出来ないことを示す。

Indicate something is not easily done. (Negative)

Japanese tends to drop a lot of pronouns, so it's ok to drop them most of the time if the subject has been established through context or you are making a generalization.

In this case the active voice makes a lot more sense than the passive voice.

やりやすい is okay to use, but the negative of it seems very strange, use やりにくい if you're trying to convey the opposite meaning.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  Would have been even better if you had  not written できない using kanji.

Comment: Why is this ba to to write it in kanji?

Comment: @Aki too complicated for people to read.